# At which point an esperantist should read the Fundamenta Krestomatio?

Tags: literature, style

Zamenhof presented the [Fundamenta Krestomatio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamenta_Krestomatio) as a model of Eo style (*modelo de esperanta stilo*). This gives the impression that any Esperantist who wants to write good Eo should read that book. But then, is it preferable to read it quite early (that is, as soon as one has an intermediate level of Eo), or after several years of practice in order to consolidate and purify one's style?

Or is the *Fundamenta Krestomatio* out of fashion and other Eo works should be prefered as models?

Comment: On my list for my Elementa Ekzameno de Esperanto as learner of Esperanto half a century ago. Though a historical work the Esperanto style is still fresh enough. And it is sufficiently light and diverse literature. Literature - out of scope of ones interests - should best be read as a way to assimilate the language at an immediate stage of E-o.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Esperanto for almost two decades and I have a copy of the *Fundamento* on my bookshelf. I have never read the *Fundamenta Krestomatio*. I've seen excerpts from it in my searching through the Tekstaro, but I always try to compare anything I find there with more modern texts if possible.

For a rough answer to the question of what should be used as models, take a look at what texts were included at tekstaro.com .

Comment: I agree. I think the tekstaro offers excellent models for understanding proper Esperanto. In addition I really like PMEG http://bertilow.com/pmeg/

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamenta Krestomatio is still a model of excellent Esperanto. Few of the expressions in it are archaic. The content isn't modern but that's all. Any Esperanto learner who masters Esperanto to the level presented in the Krestomatio should be very proud of themselves, furthermore no Esperantist who considers themselves expert could criticise you if your language was as good as that found in Krestomatio. As far as when to study it is concerned - as soon as you have a thorough grasp of the grammar and have learned between 1000 and 2000 roots and then any time after that.